# Dynamically changing Text color depending on Background Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

right now I am writing a small chrome extension. the extension grabs the Bing Image of the Day and sets it as the body background image, and then the extension also grabs the weather, time, date, etc. The problem is that sometimes the image of the day is for example, bright on one side and dark on the other. So, no matter what color the text is, some of it is illegible. How can I determine what color each text should be depending on the background image color behind a SPECIFIC text? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can toughly be done with javascript. This can be easily done on server side, like php.

Comment: add dark shadow for text, like it's done for movies subtitles for example

Comment: @Makyen Understood! will fix ASAP.

Comment: This is something of an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). It sounds like your *real* question is something like "How to display text over an image that is visible regardless of the colors used in the image." Changing the color of the text is just one method of accomplishing that.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Thanks. How so?

Comment: @Slonski I did this, and TBH, it works really well and allowed me to avoid so much trouble. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's attr() function. For example, if you img tag has an id attribute of 'my_image':

```
<img id="my_image" src="first.jpg"/>
```

Jquery
$("#my_image").attr("src","second.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

I got something to work.... It is kind of makeshift and not foolproof, but I found a script that calculates overall brightness, which then allows the script to decide whether it should display black or white text. Seems to work well, as of now. Here it is:

```js
function getImageBrightness(imageSrc) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = imageSrc;
    img.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    var colorSum = 0;
    img.onload = function () {
        // create canvas
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var data = imageData.data;
        var r, g, b, avg;

        for (var x = 0, len = data.length; x < len; x += 4) {
            r = data[x];
            g = data[x + 1];
            b = data[x + 2];

            avg = Math.floor((r + g + b) / 3);
            colorSum += avg;
        }

        brightness = Math.floor(colorSum / (this.width * this.height));
        console.log(brightness);
        if (brightness < 150) {
            $(".contrast").css("color", "white");
        } else {
            $(".contrast").css("color", "black");
        }
    }
}
```

credit to: https://jsfiddle.net/s7Wx2/

Comment: This could probably be improved if you calculated the average only over the area in which you are displaying the text, not over the entire image.

Comment: @Makyen That is correct. Any idea on how I can do that?

Comment: I have some ideas, but fleshing them out requires experimentation. To do that requires writing the code to fetch the image(s) and display the text over it. Even if I do that, I am not guaranteed to have *guessed* correctly as to how you are doing that portion of your code. Preventing the need to do that guessing and reducing the amount of work which has to be put in to duplicate code you already have are some of the reasons that having a [mcve] is strongly suggested (and required for some types of questions). Having a [mcve] also makes it more likely other people will work to find solutions.

Comment: @Makyen Understood. Ill do my best to get an example up.... unfortunately it is not as modular and organized as I would like it to be (its just a side project). But I'll look into more solutions and post here. Thanks thus far!